# VS 2013 errorC3861 PeekMessage etc and errorC2065 WNDCLASSEX

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, compiler-errors

I am attempting a new user graphics tutorial but I am very stuck. I am a very new programmer...I was under the impression that most of these definitions would be included in  I included. My message handler is missing an identifier 'DefWindowProcess', WINDCLASSEX is also not being identified, GetModuleHandle function, PeekMessage/TranslateMessage etc. The Microsoft dev center says that all these definitions should be in windows.h.

```
#ifndef _SYSTEMCLASS_H_
#define _SYSTEMCLASS_H_

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <windows.h>

#include "inputclass.h"
#include "graphicsclass.h"


class SystemClass
{
public:
SystemClass();
SystemClass(const SystemClass&);
~SystemClass();

bool Initialize();
void Shutdown();
void Run();

LRESULT CALLBACK MessageHandler(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

private:
bool Frame();
void InitializeWindows(int&, int&);
void ShutdownWindows();

private:
LPCWSTR m_applicationName;
HINSTANCE m_hinstance;
HWND m_hwnd;

InputClass* m_Input;
GraphicsClass* m_Graphics;

};

static LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

static SystemClass* ApplicationHandle = 0;

#endif
```

my systemclass.cpp is as follows

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "systemclass.h"

SystemClass::SystemClass()
{
m_Input = 0;
m_Graphics = 0;
}


bool SystemClass::Initialize()
{
int screenWidth, screenHeight;
bool result;

screenWidth = 0;
screenHeight = 0;

// Initialize the windows api.
InitializeWindows(screenWidth, screenHeight);

m_Input = new InputClass;
if (!m_Input)
{
    return false;
}

// Initialize the input object.
m_Input->Initialize();

// Create the graphics object.  This object will handle rendering all the graphics for this application.
m_Graphics = new GraphicsClass;
if (!m_Graphics)
{
    return false;
}

// Initialize the graphics object.
result = m_Graphics->Initialize(screenWidth, screenHeight, m_hwnd);
if (!result)
{
    return false;
}

return true;
}


void SystemClass::Shutdown()
{
// Release the graphics object.
if (m_Graphics)
{
    m_Graphics->Shutdown();
    delete m_Graphics;
    m_Graphics = 0;
}

// Release the input object.
if (m_Input)
{
    delete m_Input;
    m_Input = 0;
}

// Shutdown the window.
ShutdownWindows();

return;
}


void SystemClass::Run()
{
MSG msg;
bool done, result;


// Initialize the message structure.
ZeroMemory(&msg, sizeof(MSG));

// Loop until there is a quit message from the window or the user.
done = false;
while (!done)
{
    // Handle the windows messages.
    if ( PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    // If windows signals to end the application then exit out.
    if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
    {
        done = true;
    }
    else
    {
        // Otherwise do the frame processing.
        result = Frame();
        if (!result)
        {
            done = true;
        }
    }

}

return;
}


bool SystemClass::Frame()
{
bool result;


// Check if the user pressed escape and wants to exit the application.
if (m_Input->IsKeyDown(VK_ESCAPE))
{
    return false;
}

// Do the frame processing for the graphics object.
result = m_Graphics->Frame();
if (!result)
{
    return false;
}

return true;
}


LRESULT CALLBACK SystemClass::MessageHandler(HWND hwnd, UINT umsg, WPARAM   wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
switch (umsg)
{
    // Check if a key has been pressed on the keyboard.
case WM_KEYDOWN:
{

    m_Input->KeyDown((unsigned int)wparam);
    return 0;
}

// Check if a key has been released on the keyboard.
case WM_KEYUP:
{
    m_Input->KeyUp((unsigned int)wparam);
    return 0;
}

default:
{
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, umsg, wparam, lparam);
}
}
}


void SystemClass::InitializeWindows(int& screenWidth, int& screenHeight)
{
WNDCLASSEX wc; //THIS IS THE PROBLEM
DEVMODE dmScreenSettings;
int posX, posY;


// Get an external pointer to this object.  
ApplicationHandle = this;

// Get the instance of this application.
m_hinstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

// Give the application a name.
m_applicationName = L"Engine";

// Setup the windows class with default settings.
wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_OWNDC;
wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
wc.hInstance = m_hinstance;
wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_WINLOGO);
wc.hIconSm = wc.hIcon;
wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH);
wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
wc.lpszClassName = m_applicationName;
wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

// Register the window class.
RegisterClassEx(&wc);

// Determine the resolution of the clients desktop screen.
screenWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
screenHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);

    if (FULL_SCREEN)
{
            memset(&dmScreenSettings, 0, sizeof(dmScreenSettings));
    dmScreenSettings.dmSize = sizeof(dmScreenSettings);
    dmScreenSettings.dmPelsWidth = (unsigned long)screenWidth;
    dmScreenSettings.dmPelsHeight = (unsigned long)screenHeight;
    dmScreenSettings.dmBitsPerPel = 32;
    dmScreenSettings.dmFields = DM_BITSPERPEL | DM_PELSWIDTH | DM_PELSHEIGHT;

    // Change the display settings to full screen.
    ChangeDisplaySettings(&dmScreenSettings, CDS_FULLSCREEN);

    // Set the position of the window to the top left corner.
    posX = posY = 0;
}
else
{
    // If windowed then set it to 800x600 resolution.
    screenWidth = 800;
    screenHeight = 600;

    // Place the window in the middle of the screen.
    posX = (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) - screenWidth) / 2;
    posY = (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN) - screenHeight) / 2;
}

// Create the window with the screen settings and get the handle to it.
m_hwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_APPWINDOW, m_applicationName, m_applicationName,
    WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_POPUP,
    posX, posY, screenWidth, screenHeight, NULL, NULL, m_hinstance, NULL);

// Bring the window up on the screen and set it as main focus.
ShowWindow(m_hwnd, SW_SHOW);
SetForegroundWindow(m_hwnd);
SetFocus(m_hwnd);

// Hide the mouse cursor.
ShowCursor(false);

return;
}


void SystemClass::ShutdownWindows()
{
// Show the mouse cursor.
ShowCursor(true);

// Fix the display settings if leaving full screen mode.
if (FULL_SCREEN)
{
    ChangeDisplaySettings(NULL, 0);
}

// Remove the window.
DestroyWindow(m_hwnd);
m_hwnd = NULL;

// Remove the application instance.
UnregisterClass(m_applicationName, m_hinstance);
m_hinstance = NULL;

// Release the pointer to this class.
ApplicationHandle = NULL;

return;
}


LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT umessage, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
switch (umessage)
{
    // Check if the window is being destroyed.
case WM_DESTROY:
{
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    return 0;
}

// Check if the window is being closed.
case WM_CLOSE:
{
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    return 0;
}

// All other messages pass to the message handler in the system class.
default:
{
    return ApplicationHandle->MessageHandler(hwnd, umessage, wparam, lparam);
}
}
}
```

Comment: Generally you'd want to include windows.h in your precompiled header.  You might also copy/paste the exact error messages since you've misspelled quite a bit in your question.  I'd suggest reducing your code to a small simple example and see if that works and then add things to see where it breaks.  You seem to have an include problem but it isn't evident what it would be from the code you've posted.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first post as well. The error code reads: error C3861: 'PeekMessage': identifier not found...same for all others except WNDCLASSEX which has error C2065. So I need to have my header precompiled to get my build to work??

Comment: You can edit your question to include the copy/pasted errors.  You do not ever need a precompiled header, but if you're using one it can screw some things up if you do it wrong.  Without seeing more code all anyone could do is guess.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, directx projects don't recognize window API, I needed a win32 project, apply #stdafx headers on all my cpp files to get precompiled headers to work an also add #pragma once to all header files to avoid pch errors. VS is a bit quirky it turns out. Also for all the other noobs, make sure you set up file paths for directx and that you add files through project ->add->newfile->appropriate file type. it will save you headaches from VS knowing correct file locations.